# SQL queries to only show most recent purchase records for individual food items

Tags: join, ms-access, date, sorting, distinct

I'm working with a food purchasing / invoice system in MS Access 2013 and am trying to create an SQL query that will return the most recent purchase price for each individual food item.

Here is a diagram of the tables I'm working with:
[image: Tables in MS Access database]

My understanding of SQL is very basic, and I tried the following (incorrect) query, in the hopes that it would return only one record per item (because of the `DISTINCT` operator) and that it would only return the most recent purchase (since I did `ORDER BY [Invoice Date] DESC`)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ([Food items].Item), 
    [Food items].Item, [Food purchase data].[Price per unit], [Food purchase data].[Purchase unit], Invoices.[Invoice Date]
FROM Invoices
INNER JOIN ([Food items] 
    INNER JOIN [Food purchase data] 
    ON [Food items].ID = [Food purchase data].[Food item ID]) 
ON Invoices.ID = [Food purchase data].[Invoice ID]
ORDER BY Invoices.[Invoice Date] DESC;
```

However the query above simply returns all of the food purchases (i.e. multiple records for each record in `[Food items]`), with the results sorted descending by date. Can someone explain to me what I am misunderstanding about the `DISTINCT` operator? That is, why is it not returning only one record for each item in `[Food items]`?

And more to the point - **what is the *simplest* way for me to just pull the most recent food purchase data for each individual food item, given the table structure shown above**? I don't really care about efficiency as much as simplicity (the database I'm working with is rather small - it will be years before it's even in the tens of thousands of records range). I care more about the query being understandable for someone with little knowledge of SQL.

**UPDATE:**
So I tried, both of the answers suggested below, and neither of them work (they just throw up syntax errors).

Based on the suggestions below, and further reading online, I wrote the following new query, using the aggregate function `max()` and a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT [Food purchase data].[Food item ID], [Food purchase data].[Price per unit], max(Invoices.[Invoice Date]) AS MostRecentInvoiceDate
FROM [Food purchase data], Invoices
GROUP BY [Food purchase data].[Food item ID], [Food purchase data].[Price per unit];
```

But I am still having the same problem: that is, I'm still seeing more than one result for each food item. **Can anyone explain why this query is not only returning the most recent purchase for each food item?**

**UPDATE 2 (SOLVED!)**:

None of the answers below quite worked out but based on some heavy modification of Vladimir's [answer below](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122781/70214), I was able to create the following queries, which appear to be giving the correct results.

First, I created this view and named it "LatestInvoices":

```
SELECT InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID, InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate, InvoicesMaxDate.MaxID
FROM [Food purchase data], Invoices, (SELECT [Food purchase data].[Food item ID] AS ItemID, MAX(Invoices.[Invoice Date]) AS MaxDate, MAX(Invoices.[Invoice ID]) AS MaxID
                FROM [Food purchase data], Invoices
                WHERE Invoices.[Invoice ID] = [Food purchase data].[Invoice ID]
                GROUP BY [Food purchase data].[Food item ID]
         )  AS InvoicesMaxDate
WHERE InvoicesMaxDate.MaxID = [Food purchase data].[Invoice ID] AND
                      InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID = [Food purchase data].[Food item ID] AND 
                      InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate = Invoices.[Invoice Date]
GROUP BY InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID, InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate,  InvoicesMaxDate.MaxID
```

Then I wrote another query to pull in the fields I needed:

```
SELECT [Food items].ID AS FoodItemID, [Food items].Item AS FoodItem, [Food purchase data].[Price], [Food purchase data].[Price per unit], [Food purchase data].[Purchase unit], LatestInvoices.MaxDate as InvoiceDate
FROM [Food items], [Food purchase data], LatestInvoices
WHERE LatestInvoices.[MaxID] = [Food purchase data].[Invoice ID] AND
             LatestInvoices.ItemID = [Food purchase data].[Food item ID] AND
             LatestInvoices.ItemID = [Food items].ID
ORDER BY [Food items].Item;
```

Thanks to all of you who took the time to help me with this!

Comment: `DISTINCT` returns rows that are distinct across all columns in the row, not single columns.

Comment: Just a word of advice, avoid using spaces in your table and column names.  Then you'll not need to surround everything with `[` and `]`

Comment: And it is (arguably) best to include the name of the table in all the `ID` columns, so `ID` in the `Invoices` table becomes `InvoiceID`.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense - I thought that `DISTINCT` was by single columns. Is there an analogous operator that will select only based on uniqueness in a single column? Also, thanks for the tips on naming conventions - yes, it is very annoying to have to use `[ ... ]` everywhere ... And I can see how including the table name in the ID column would increase readability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MS Access is rather limited.

I assume that it is possible to have more than one invoice for the same date.
In this case I'll pick an invoice with the highest ID.

At first we'll find maximum Invoice Date for each Food Item.

```
SELECT
    FPD1.[Food item ID] AS ItemID
    ,MAX(I1.[Invoice Date]) AS MaxDate
FROM
    [Food purchase data] AS FPD1
    INNER JOIN Invoices AS I1 ON I1.ID = FPD1.[Invoice ID]
GROUP BY
    FPD1.[Food item ID]
```

Since it is possible that there are several invoices for the found max date we'll pick one invoice with the max ID per Item

Based on the [MS Access syntax of nested joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff197346.aspx) and using this example from the docs:

> ```
> SELECT fields 
> FROM 
>   table1 INNER JOIN 
>   (
>       table2 INNER JOIN 
>       (
>           table3 INNER JOIN tablex ON table3.field3 = tablex.fieldx
>       ) ON table2.field2 = table3.field3
>   ) ON table1.field1 = table2.field2
> ;
> ```

Let's try to put it together:

```
SELECT
    InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID
    ,InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate
    ,MAX(I2.ID) AS MaxInvoiceID
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            FPD1.[Food item ID] AS ItemID
            ,MAX(I1.[Invoice Date]) AS MaxDate
        FROM
            [Food purchase data] AS FPD1
            INNER JOIN Invoices AS I1 ON I1.ID = FPD1.[Invoice ID]
        GROUP BY
            FPD1.[Food item ID]
    ) AS InvoicesMaxDate INNER JOIN
    (
        [Food purchase data] AS FPD2 
        INNER JOIN Invoices AS I2 ON I2.ID = FPD2.[Invoice ID]
    ) ON
        InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID = FPD2.[Food item ID] AND
        --- you may need to put extra "ON" here as well, not sure
        InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate = I2.[Invoice Date]
GROUP BY
    InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID
    ,InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate
```

Now we have both ItemID and ID of the last Invoice for that Item.
Join this to original tables to fetch other details (columns).

```
SELECT
    FI3.Item
    ,FI3.Item
    ,FPD3.[Price per unit]
    ,FPD3.[Purchase unit]
    ,I3.[Invoice Date]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID
            ,InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate
            ,MAX(I2.ID) AS MaxInvoiceID
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    FPD1.[Food item ID] AS ItemID
                    ,MAX(I1.[Invoice Date]) AS MaxDate
                FROM
                    [Food purchase data] AS FPD1
                    INNER JOIN Invoices AS I1 ON I1.ID = FPD1.[Invoice ID]
                GROUP BY
                    FPD1.[Food item ID]
            ) AS InvoicesMaxDate INNER JOIN
            (
                [Food purchase data] AS FPD2 
                INNER JOIN Invoices AS I2 ON I2.ID = FPD2.[Invoice ID]
            ) ON
                InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID = FPD2.[Food item ID] AND
                InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate = I2.[Invoice Date]
        GROUP BY
            InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID
            ,InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate
    ) AS LastInvoices INNER JOIN
    (
        [Food items] AS FI3 INNER JOIN
        (
            [Food purchase data] AS FPD3
            INNER JOIN Invoices AS I3 ON I3.ID = FPD3.[Invoice ID]
        ) ON FI3.ID = FDP3.[Food item ID]
    ) ON
        LastInvoices.MaxInvoiceID = I3.ID AND
        LastInvoices.ItemID = FI3.ID
```

In practice I'd create a view for the first query with a single join. Then I'd create a second view that joins the first view with the tables, then the third view and so on, to avoid the nested joins or minimize them. Overall query would be easier to read.

---

**Edit** to clarify what I mean based on your final solution that you put into the question.

One last attempt to convey my message.

This is what **you** wrote based on my suggestions above:

```
SELECT
    InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID
    ,InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate
    ,Invoices.[Invoice ID]
FROM [Food purchase data], Invoices, 
    (
        SELECT 
            [Food purchase data].[Food item ID] AS ItemID
            ,MAX(Invoices.[Invoice Date]) AS MaxDate
        FROM [Food purchase data], Invoices
        WHERE Invoices.[Invoice ID] = [Food purchase data].[Invoice ID]
        GROUP BY [Food purchase data].[Food item ID]
    )  AS InvoicesMaxDate
WHERE
    Invoices.[Invoice ID] = [Food purchase data].[Invoice ID] AND
    InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID = [Food purchase data].[Food item ID] AND 
    InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate = Invoices.[Invoice Date]
GROUP BY InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID, InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate, Invoices.[Invoice ID];
```

This is what **I** meant:

```
SELECT
    InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID
    ,InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate
    ,MAX(Invoices.[Invoice ID]) AS [Invoice ID]
FROM [Food purchase data], Invoices, 
    (
        SELECT
            [Food purchase data].[Food item ID] AS ItemID
            ,MAX(Invoices.[Invoice Date]) AS MaxDate
        FROM [Food purchase data], Invoices
        WHERE Invoices.[Invoice ID] = [Food purchase data].[Invoice ID]
        GROUP BY [Food purchase data].[Food item ID]
    )  AS InvoicesMaxDate
WHERE
    Invoices.[Invoice ID] = [Food purchase data].[Invoice ID] AND
    InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID = [Food purchase data].[Food item ID] AND 
    InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate = Invoices.[Invoice Date]
GROUP BY InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID, InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate;
```

Do you see the difference?

The `InvoicesMaxDate` returns MAX `Invoice Date` for each `Food item ID`.
If there are two invoices for the same `Food item ID` with the same MAX `Invoice Date` we should pick one invoice among them.
This is done by grouping by `InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID, InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate`. 
There should be **no** grouping by `Invoices.[Invoice ID]` here, because we want to pick the invoice with the maximum ID.

Once you have this query saved as a `LatestInvoices` view, it is used further as you correctly wrote (note, that the final query uses `LatestInvoices.[Invoice ID]` and `LatestInvoices.ItemID`, but doesn't use `LatestInvoices.MaxDate`):

```
SELECT 
    [Food items].ID as FoodItemID
    ,[Food items].Item as FoodItem
    ,[Food purchase data].[Price]
    ,[Food purchase data].[Price per unit]
    ,[Food purchase data].[Purchase unit]
    ,Invoices.[Invoice Date]
FROM [Food items], [Food purchase data], Invoices, LatestInvoices
WHERE 
    Invoices.[Invoice ID] = [Food purchase data].[Invoice ID] AND
    [Food items].ID = [Food purchase data].[Food item ID] AND
    LatestInvoices.[Invoice ID] = Invoices.[Invoice ID] AND 
    LatestInvoices.ItemID = [Food items].ID
ORDER BY [Food items].Item
```

---

As for, why your last query in the question returns several rows per Item:

```
SELECT 
    [Food purchase data].[Food item ID]
    , [Food purchase data].[Price per unit]
    , max(Invoices.[Invoice Date]) AS MostRecentInvoiceDate
FROM [Food purchase data], Invoices
GROUP BY [Food purchase data].[Food item ID], [Food purchase data].[Price per unit];
```

You are grouping here by `[Food item ID]` and `[Price per unit]`, so you'll get as many rows as there are unique combinations of these two columns.

The following query would return one row per `[Food item ID]`.

```
SELECT 
    [Food purchase data].[Food item ID]
    , max(Invoices.[Invoice Date]) AS MostRecentInvoiceDate
FROM [Food purchase data], Invoices
GROUP BY [Food purchase data].[Food item ID];
```

A side note, you really should use explicit `INNER JOIN` instead of `,`. That syntax is 20 years old.

```
SELECT 
    [Food purchase data].[Food item ID]
    , max(Invoices.[Invoice Date]) AS MostRecentInvoiceDate
FROM
    [Food purchase data]
    INNER JOIN Invoices ON Invoices.ID = [Food purchase data].[Invoice ID]
GROUP BY [Food purchase data].[Food item ID];
```

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer! The first query you shared worked, and did indeed pull the most recent invoice date for each individual food item, which is really helpful. However, when I tried the next 2 queries you shared I got `"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression"` in the expression `INNER JOIN Invoices AS I2 ON I2.ID = FPD2.[Invoice ID]` ... I'll play around with it more to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @JesseTaylor, apparently, it is necessary to explicitly put brackets `(` and `)` when query uses several [joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff197346.aspx) and to move the `ON` clause around a bit. I don't have Access to check, but I can try to guess the correct syntax by reading the docs later today.

Comment: @JesseTaylor, I updated the answer and hope I guesses the syntax correctly. Please try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggested queries are still giving syntax errors. Access error messages are completely useless, and give no indication as to where the errors are specifically (all it says is "Syntax error in JOIN operation", without specifying which join or what the error is). Anyways, I deeply appreciate all of the work you have done trying to help me out. Hopefully I'll be able to piece it together from your and other people's answers here ...

Comment: Wow! I modified your query to remove some of the variable names and rewrote the JOIN statements as WHERE clauses ... with a bit of fiddling, I finally got it to work. I'll post the working query as an update to the original question. Again, I can't thank you enough for taking so much time to help me figure this out. Although your suggestions didn't quite work, I'm going to accept your answer and award you the bounty because my solution was based on yours. You rock!

Comment: @JesseTaylor, you are welcome. It's been a while since I used Access and it is hard to get its syntax right. One note about your view `LatestInvoices`: the final `GROUP` should be `BY InvoicesMaxDate.ItemID, InvoicesMaxDate.MaxDate` only, without `Invoices.[Invoice ID]`. In the `SELECT` part there should be `MAX(Invoices.[Invoice ID]) AS [Invoice ID]`. This is the whole point. At first (in the inner query) we `GROUP BY [Food item ID]` and find the maximum Invoice Date. There can be several invoices with this date, so there is a second `GROUP BY` to pick invoice with maximum ID among them.

Comment: Thanks again Vladimir - I updated the answer to correct it as you suggested.

Comment: @JesseTaylor, Unfortunately, you misunderstood me. I updated my answer to show you what I meant. To see the difference add two invoices to your (sample) data for the same `ItemID` with the same large date and try both queries.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and assistance. I updated it, and I see now the difference (I hadn't realized that some of them were duplicated where there were multiple purchases on the same day).

Answer (score 3):

A query that just works out of the box:

```
SELECT Fi.Item, Fpd.[Price per unit], Fpd.[Purchase unit]
FROM [Food items] Fi INNER JOIN [Food purchase data] Fpd
ON Fpd.[Food item ID] = Fi.ID
WHERE Fpd.[Invoice ID] = (
  SELECT TOP 1 I.ID 
  FROM Invoices I INNER JOIN [Food purchase data] Fpd2
  ON Fpd2.[Invoice ID] = I.ID
  WHERE Fpd2.[Food item ID] = Fpd.[Food item ID]
  ORDER BY I.[Invoice Date] DESC
)
```

Comment: When I run this query, I just get an error: "At most one record can be returned by this subquery." The datasheet view just shows one record with "#NAME?" in every field.

Answer (score 3):

I could solve it with the following query:

```
Select MAX(AllItemBuyings.[invoice date]) as RecentBuyingDate, AllItemBuyings.[Food Item Id]  From 
(    
    select fpd.[Invoice Id], fpd.[Food Item Id], I.[invoice date] From [Food purchase data]as fpd 
    inner join invoices I on fpd.[Invoice Id] = I.ID

) as AllItemBuyings    
Group By AllItemBuyings.[Food Item Id]
```

Because I do not have Access I tested this on SQL Server. I hope this will work for you.

**Edit/Additional query**:
In order to add the other columns of the food item table I changed the query. I did it in a way I do not really like. If it's ok for you depends on your data and requirements. I joined the INVOICES table again by using the Order Date. In case this is a date including time that my work out, please be aware of that. I do not see another way in your scenario. Maybe there is a better solution using recursive query...?

Please give it a try and let me know if it works:

```
Select Recents.RecentBuyingDate, pd.* From 
(

   Select MAX(AllItemBuyings.[invoice date]) as RecentBuyingDate, AllItemBuyings.[Food Item Id]    From 
    (    
        select fpd.[Invoice Id], fpd.[Food Item Id], I.[invoice date], fpd.ID From [Food purchase data]as fpd 
        inner join invoices I on fpd.[Invoice Id] = I.ID

    ) as AllItemBuyings    
    Group By AllItemBuyings.[Food Item Id]

    ) as Recents    
    Join Invoices i on i.[invoice date] = Recents.RecentBuyingDate
    Join [Food purchase data] pd ON pd.[Invoice Id] = i.ID AND pd.[Food Item Id] = Recents.[Food Item Id]
```

Comment: Thank you. This correctly gives me the most recent purchase date for each item. How would I use this, though, to pull in all of the fields that I mentioned in the question (e.g. `Item`, `Price per unit`, etc)?

Comment: The new query you suggested just throws up an error message that says nothing other than "Syntax error in FROM clause."

Comment: Maybe Access requires the JOIN operation to be exactly "INNER JOIN". Try INNSER JOIN instead of just JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the below should work.

```
SELECT fi.[Item], fd.[Price per unit], MAX(i.[Invoice Date])
FROM [Invoices] AS i
INNER JOIN [Food Purchase Data] AS fd
    ON i.ID = fd.[Invoice ID]
INNER JOIN [Food items] AS fi
    ON fd.[Food item ID] = fi.ID
GROUP BY fi.Item, fd.[Price per unit]
ORDER BY i.[Invoice Date] DESC
```

As for why your query is not returning the results youd like:

```
SELECT [Food purchase data].[Food item ID], [Food purchase data].[Price per unit], max(Invoices.[Invoice Date]) AS MostRecentInvoiceDate
FROM [Food purchase data], Invoices
GROUP BY [Food purchase data].[Food item ID], [Food purchase data].[Price per unit];
```

The biggest issue I see is that you aren't really doing anything to join your tables. The implicit "join" that is present by simply listing both in your FROM clause is giving you a Cartesian product.
Basically it will return every possible combination in your database for the fields you're querying.

For example if the two tables had 3 records each instead of returning the most recent date, your query would return something like:
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
3,1
3,2
3,3

It's very important that you explicitly declare your joins. Two ways you could do so in your query would be:

```
FROM [Food purchase data] AS fd, [Invoices] AS i
WHERE fd.[Invoice ID] = i.[ID]
```

OR

```
FROM [Food purchase data] AS fd
INNER JOIN [Invoices] AS i
    ON fd.[Invoice ID] = i.[ID]
```

Updated queries, if those still don't work try removing the aliases and using the fully qualified column names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32524/discussion-between-agpoweredmg-and-jesse-taylor).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Max's suggestions about your data model. Implementing those will make your SQL more readable in the long run.

With that said, DISTINCT will display unique rows. So to only show the most recent, you must limit the columns displayed.

Try something like:

```
SELECT [Food purchase data].[Food item ID], max(Invoices.[Invoice Date]) AS MostRecentInvoiceDate
FROM Invoices 
INNER JOIN ([Food items] ON [Food items].ID = [Food purchase data].[Food item ID]) 
GROUP BY [Food purchase data].[Food item ID]
```

(Translation: For each item in the store, display its most recent invoice date.)

You can save this as a view and use it in another query like you would a table. So you can do an inner join on the invoice for the purchase price and joins on the other tables if you need those details.

(Theoretically, you could also do a nested query, but since you requested simple, a saved query is simpler.)

**UPDATE based on your update:**

I'm going to use WHERE clauses instead of JOINS because I don't have MS Access handy. You should be able to use the GUI to make the connections between the tables in MS Access based on this information. (Please provide a SQLFiddle if you really need help with further troubleshooting.)

Step 1: Save this as a VIEW (For example, "MostRecentInvoice")

```
SELECT [Food purchase data].[Food item ID] AS FoodItemID, max(Invoices.[Invoice Date]) AS MostRecentInvoiceDate
FROM [Food purchase data], Invoices
WHERE [Food purchase data].[Food item ID] = Invoices.ID
GROUP BY [Food purchase data].[Food item ID];
```

Step 2: Use the view in a 2nd query

```
SELECT (list all the fields you need here)
FROM MostRecentInvoice, Invoices, etc...
WHERE MostRecentInvoice.FoodItemID = [Food purchase data].[Food item ID] 
AND MostRecentInvoice.MostRecentInvoiceDate = Invoices.[Invoice Date]
AND (whatever else joins you'll need for the other tables)
```

...and to answer your question:
The 2nd query in the update doesn't work because the [Price per unit] column is in your SELECT and GROUP BY statements. This essentially means you're asking to see ALL possible values of [Price per unit] even though what you really want is only one: the most recent value.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to run the query you shared I just get an error: "Syntax error in JOIN operation."

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time to create the tables in Access myself. I assumed you had a bit of experiences with joins since there were some in your question. Did you try to create it by doing Create -> Query in Access?

Comment: The first query you shared doesn't give correct results because of the line `WHERE [Food purchase data].[Food item ID] = Invoices.ID` ... I assume you meant `WHERE [Food purchase data].[Invoice ID] = Invoices.[Invoice ID]` but that still returns multiple dates per food item instead of just the most recent.